# versions on android emulator using eclipse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am running android emulator v 4.0.3 using eclipse. Is there a way to run different versions of android( for testing purposes) on the same emulator. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to make a new Android Virtual Device to run it, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can download different versions of Android SDK and run them on the emulator.

See here:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html

Comment: I installed the sdk as mentioned above and created a new AVD(metioned above by CBredlow and it created fine) and tried to install my app on the new avd. why dont I see the newly created avd under run configs --> target. can some one please help!

Comment: Thanks! got it working. from the above two steps. install sdk and create new avd. run new device and then install apk files as usual